# mysqli_affected_rows always return 1

Tags: php, mysql

I got some problem with mysqli_affected_rows, it return 1 all times even update not effected.

```
$dbConnect = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass);
$dbSelect = mysql_select_db($dbName, $dbConnect);

$sqlprove = mysql_query('UPDATE '.tblAVB.' SET a= "1" WHERE id= "'.$_POST['id'].'" AND Active = "1" ');

$isprove = mysqli_affected_rows($sqlprove);
```

can any body help me?

Comment: `mysqli != mysql`. they're two completely separate and independent libraries in PHP. results/handles from one library are **NOT** usable in the other library's calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `mysqli` then you use *only* `mysqli` prefixed functions. You cannot mix and match with the deprecated `mysql_query` methods.

In fact, you should not be using `mysql_query` at all if you're using `mysqli`.

If you're just getting started you should be using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead. The `mysqli` interface is better than the legacy one, but it's fairly annoying and cantankerous compared to PDO.

In any case, you **must** be very careful to always use [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) on any and all values.

Comment: Better than messing with SQL escaping is to use proper parametrized queries.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html gives some examples.

Comment: If you **absolutely** must use `mysql_query`, then yes. I highly recommend you do not. It is extremely hazardous if used incorrectly. In your example you have created a **severe** SQL injection bug because you have not escaped your `$_POST` value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i have this one, it work but i don't want to use  Object oriented style in middle of the codes:

```
$mysqli->query('UPDATE '.tblAVB.' SET a= "1" WHERE id= "'.$_POST['id'].'" AND Active = "1" ');

$prove = $mysqli->affected_rows;
```

and the Procedural style not work!!!!!
because i connect it to db before query and not use $link!!!!

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE Language SET Status=1 WHERE Percentage > 50");
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
```

is it because i use **mysql** rather mysqli?
is there a way to get affected_rows for mysql?
[reference](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.mysqli-affected-rows.htm)

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, then you *must* use the SQL placeholders feature. The query should look like `where id=?` and later you will use `bind_param` to assign the `$_POST` to it.